# removing readonly attribute from win 7 directory (c:\dev)

Tags: mongodb, installation, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to run mongo via the cmd prompt (mongod) as Administrator taking the default values. The data\db dirs exist yet the process fails stating it doesn't. I noticed all the dirs under and including c:\dev which has the mongo dir as a sub dir are readonly. I'm assuming that the db isn't allowed to initialize and create itself because of the readonly. I don't want to move the binaries to my Local\AppData dir. I tried using icals and attrib commands but it's a nogo still.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get mongod to run on win 7 you have to use the --dbpath flag

Answer (score 0):

As long as the files in c:\data\db are not readonly for the user you are running as the default directory should work. I run it as such.